# How to detect whether use `.inputrc` or not

Tags: cygwin, git-bash, mintty, inputrc

I need add

```
"\e[1;5C": forward-word   # ctrl + right
"\e[1;5D": backward-word  # ctrl + left
```

in `~/.inputrc`  to make tmux works in msys2.

But this would corrupt git-bash,  how do I make only msys2 load that settings?

Answer (score 1):

inputrc supports conditionals based on program name and terminal name ($TERM):

```
$if term=xterm
...
$endif
```

See the `readline(3)` manual page.